# I have WPBakery page builder in WordPress. when I edit my home page with this builder then no out put on front end page how to solve this?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, visual-composer

I have WP Bakery page builder in WordPress when I edit my home page with this builder then there is no output on front end how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you using the latest updated version of VC.
2. Try deactivation other plugins.
3. increase PHP memory of your site to 256M